# Spring JMS junit test can't find @Component annotated receiver

Tags: java, spring, junit, jms, autowired

I'm trying to test JMSSender and JMSReceiver, the JMSSender is autowiring correctly, but the JMSReceiver is not.

> No qualifying bean of type
>   'br.com.framework.TestJMSReceiverImpl' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

The test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JMSSenderConfig.class, JMSReceiverConfig.class })
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.activemq.broker-url = vm://localhost:61616" })
public class SpringJmsApplicationTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedActiveMQBroker broker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker();

    @Autowired
    private JMSSender sender;

    @Autowired
    private TestJMSReceiverImpl receiver;

    @Test
    public void testReceive() throws Exception {
        sender.send("helloworld.q", "Daleee");
        receiver.receive();
    }
}
```

main Application class i have:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("br.com.framework")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

The TestJMSReceiverImpl:

```
@Component
public class TestJMSReceiverImpl extends JMSReceiver {

    public TestJMSReceiverImpl() {
        super("helloworld.q");
    }
    ...
}
```

The JMSReceiver:

```
public abstract class JMSReceiver {

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private String queue;

    public JMSReceiver(String queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Anyone knows what I am missing here?

Comment: Is `TestJMSReceiverImpl` included when scanning? (is it in the right package?)

Comment: it was on package br.com.framework, it's the right one i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TestJMSReceiverImpl` class is not included in your test context. You need to add it the context configuration for the `SpringJmsApplicationTest` class: change

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JMSSenderConfig.class, JMSReceiverConfig.class })
```

into

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JMSSenderConfig.class,
JMSReceiverConfig.class, TestJMSReceiverImpl.class })
```